# Swift error: cannot convert value of type B to type A in coercion

Tags: swift, generics

I have an generic class A and its subclass B:

```
class A<T1: Any,T2: Any> {
    let x: T1
    let y: T2
    init (_ v1: T1, _ v2: T2) {
        self.x=v1
        self.y=v2
    }
}

class B<T: Any>: A<T,T> {
    init (_ v: T) {
        super.init(v,v)
    }
}
```

I need a collection of different objects, all of them belong to subclassess of A:

```
var arr=[A<Any,Any>]()
```

But I cannot put objects into the collection, the following code causes an error:

```
let t=B(10)
arr.append(t as A<Any,Any>)
```

The error is:

> cannot convert value of type 'B' to type 'A' (aka
>   'A, protocol<>>') in coercion

How to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Declare `t` as `B<Any>` (the inferred type by the compiler is `B<Int>`):

```
let t: B<Any> = B(10)
arr.append(t) // works
```

Comment: Thsnks, but what if I need to put into arr existing variable?

Comment: So when you first create your variable, let it has a specific type (that is, if your variable is called "a". dont make "var a = ..." but make "var a: B<Any> = ..."